# Can light be used as a medium to propagate sound waves on?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, acoustics

My understanding of why sound cannot travel through space is because sound waves are a disruption wave that require a medium to traverse on, therefore sound can only go as far as the medium it's on goes; in a vacuum, sound cannot be propagated because there is nothing to propagate it on.

I came across some article that I dont remember the details of, regarding an experiment testing whether sound waves can be propagated on a beam of light using lasers.

Is this possible theoretically? Because light is both wave and particle.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but not in the way you are probably thinking.

A simple example is to shine a laser pointer at a photoconductor connected to a battery and a loudspeaker. Place a spinning electric fan blade in the light beam so the blade chops it up. Each time a burst of light hits the photoconductor, it conducts and permits a pulse of current to flow from the battery through the loudspeaker, which converts the light burst into sound.

I used this setup to demonstrate to 2nd grade school students how to carry sound over a light beam.

Comment: kinda like fibre optics, but without the fibre